# database not being copied to the iPhone device from resources

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have come up with a strange problem. I am using sqlite database in my app. The app works fine when running in the simulator but when I deploy the app on iPhone device, it doesn't read from the db. Also, when I try to insert something to a table, it say no such table, which means that my db is not actually copied to the device. I hav tried cleaning the project with Build->Clean all Targets, delete the Build folder and manually remove the app from the device. Then try building again. but no luck. Certainly, I have added the db to the Resources and I can locate and actually read the contents. Please guide me whats wrong when deploying on the device.

Comment: Have you copied your db file to documents directory? if not do it at the first place and read the db whenever you want to do CRUD operations in it.

Answer (score 0):

First check that you are copying the db into the bundle in the copy resources build phase. When a resource is in the bundle you cannot modify it, you need to copy it to the application's document directory

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually never managed to get this right. That's why I've a build script setup that dumps any sqlite DB that i have into a .sql text file. On the first run of the app on the phone, i just generate the sqlite DB from these sql lines. Works much saver for me than working with the binary files from sqlite.